# Implementing a Graph object in java

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

So I am attempting to create a DFS and BFS algorithm but cannot seem to get the graph object populated as I receive the error `Graph object cannot be resolved to a type`. Is there something I am missing when importing from the java library? As always thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Maze {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Graph myGraph= new Graph(); //  <- error resides here.


myGraph.addconnection(0, 3);
myGraph.addconnection(0, 5);
myGraph.addconnection(1, 4);
myGraph.addconnection(2, 3);
myGraph.addconnection(5, 4);
myGraph.addconnection(5, 7);
myGraph.addconnection(6, 7);
myGraph.addconnection(7, 8);
myGraph.addconnection(8, 9);
myGraph.addconnection(9, 10);
myGraph.addconnection(11, 3);
```

Comment: you have to import Graph - if it's packed within an external library(jar) you have to add that jar to your class path

Comment: Ok I thought that might be the problem, I will try that now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`import` for class Graph is missing**

Add required `jars` to your classpath and build

Comment: Thanks all sorted now :)